# Generate dynamic sliders for filtering in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In Shiny, rather than manually typing out each slider for filtering a dataframe, which is in reality much larger than this, I use the following code to dynamically produce sliders, each with the appropriate range for its column, through the use of a single functional (lapply):

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(a = 0:10, b = 20:30, c = 80:90)

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Filter DF"),

        mainPanel(
           tableOutput("df"),
           uiOutput("sliders")
        )
    )


server <- function(input, output) {

    tmp_df <- reactive({
      dat %>% filter(a > 5) # blah blah
    })

    output$df <- renderTable({
      tmp_df()
    })

    output$sliders <- renderUI({

      t <- tmp_df()
      pvars <- names(t)

      lapply(pvars, function(nm) {

        min <- min(t[[nm]], na.rm = TRUE)
        max <- max(t[[nm]], na.rm = TRUE)

        sliderInput(inputId = paste0("range_", nm),
                    label = nm,
                    min = min,
                    max = max,
                    value = c(min, max))
      })

    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But I would also like to dynamically create the code which enables each slider to filter (using dplyr) the dataframe with each slider's current values.

How could I do this?

Comment: I think this is a job for a [module](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html)...

Comment: Thanks @Limey. That drove the solution, now posted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Limey for the head's up.

**Solution:**

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


dat <- data.frame(a = 0:10, b = 20:30, c = 80:90)
nms <- names(dat)


sliderUI <- function(id) {

  ns <- NS(id)

  min <- min(dat[[id]], na.rm = TRUE)
  max <- max(dat[[id]], na.rm = TRUE)

  sliderInput(inputId = ns('slider'),
              label = id,
              min = min,
              max = max,
              value = c(min, max))
}

sliderServer <- function(df, id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      id <- as.name(id)
      df %>% filter(dplyr::between(!!id, input$slider[1], input$slider[2]))
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  map(nms, sliderUI),
  tableOutput("df")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  tmp_df <- reactive({ dat })

  output$df <- renderTable({
    purrr::reduce(nms, sliderServer, .init = tmp_df())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```